# How to union two spark dataframes by alternating rows? How about if the order should be "fibonacci-style"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with PySpark. I have two dataframes, A and B, and would like to get a new dataframe, where

> row 1 is row 1 from A,
> row 2 is row 1 from B
> row 3 is row 2 from A
> row 4 is row 2 from B
> row 5 is row 3 from A ...

The solution should also handle cases when the data frames have different lengths. Then there would be first the alternating rows, and then the longer list would be added in the end of the data frame.

Also, I would like to test if Fibonacci style ordering beats this alternating style. For that I mean that the rows would come from different dataframes like ABABAABAAAB. Here the amount of As comes from Fibonacci series.

Answer (score 0):

There is no order in pyspark dataframes and the first row is meaningless. but I assume you have a col "row_number" which identifies index of each row.
you can do a trick and multiply row numbers of a and b dataframes to 2 and then add 1 to b dataframe row numbers, union a and b dataframe and at last do a new row numbering

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

a_df.show()
+----------+---+
|row_number|col|
+----------+---+
|         1|  a|
|         2|  b|
|         3|  c|
+----------+---+
b_df.show()
+----------+---+
|row_number|col|
+----------+---+
|         1|  d|
|         2|  e|
|         3|  f|
|         4|  g|
|         5|  h|
+----------+---+

(
    a_df
    .withColumn('new_row_number', F.col('row_number')*2 - 1)
    .union(
        b_df
        .withColumn('new_row_number', F.col('row_number')*2))
    .withColumn(
        'new_row_number', 
        F.row_number()
        .over(W.orderBy('new_row_number')))
).show()

+----------+---+--------------+
|row_number|col|new_row_number|
+----------+---+--------------+
|         1|  a|             1|
|         1|  d|             2|
|         2|  b|             3|
|         2|  e|             4|
|         3|  c|             5|
|         3|  f|             6|
|         4|  g|             7|
|         5|  h|             8|
+----------+---+--------------+
```

Comment: If there's no order, what does `orderBy` do?

Comment: Thanks! I don't have row numbers, but a score value that was used to order the rows. Adding an extra column would solve this work. If it is used only for sorting, one table having values like 0,1,2,3 and another like (0,1,2,3)+0.5 = 0.5, 1.5, 2,5  would do the trick

Comment: @RVa Yes, you are right. I was biased with an old memory so I just repeated my mind xD.